# Compartir objeto de una clase Parcelable entre Actividades en Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Algún ejemplo práctico de como seria compartir una classe implementando `Parcelable` para compartir un objeto entre Actividades?

La clase ya la tengo definida

```
public class Interstitial extends Banner implements Parcelable {
...
```

El objeto que quiero compartir entre actividades

```
    Interstitial entryAd.setType(Interstitial.TypeInterstitial.APPGAME);
    entryAd.setTitle1("Your internet-100X Faster");
    ...
```

Me falta armar el `Intent` y recibir el `intent` para recuperar el objeto en la otra actividad.

Comment: porque el objeto debe implementar Parcelable?

Comment: Muy buenas @Elenasys mm pues ni idea, tengo entendido que en Android es mejor usar parcelable, antes lo tenia sin y debo pasar muchos parametros por putExtra y era para optimizar más el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El intent lo puedes armar de la siguiente manera:

Para el envio:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("nombre_extra", objectoParcelable);
```

Recibes:

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
  ObjectoParcelable objectoParcelable = (ObjectoParcelable) i.getParcelableExtra("nombre_extra");
```

**Extra**

Este enlace te lleva a un generador de Objetos parcelables

http://www.parcelabler.com/

Saludos.

Comment: Una observación el mismo Android studio me informa que el = (ObjectoParcelable) se puede quitar porque es rendundante

Answer (score 2):

### Enviar objetos entre Actividades:

Una opción es implementar en tu objeto la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) o [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable):

```
public class Interstitial implements Serializable {
```

o también :

```
public class Interstitial implements Parcelable {
```

Enviarias un ArrayList de objetos en el `Intent` mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("listaInterstitial", listaInterstitial);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList de objetos en la Activity se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<listaInterstitial> listaInterstitial = (ArrayList<listaInterstitial> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listaInterstitial");
```