# Android Studio transferir objetos entre activities

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Hola estoy teniendo un problema, y es que no se como enviar un objeto a otra activity. me dijeron que podia a traves del putExtras(), del intent. Pero no pude

[image: Creo que esto es lo que me dijeron para implementarlo, pero aun asi me dice que null dentro]

Comment: Recuerda que SOes es un sitio de preguntas concretas y respuestas aun mas concretas, siempre es necesario que nos muestres lo que llevas hecho, que nos muestres el esfuerzo y los errores que te han surgido, y asi tambien que nos plantees tu duda, mas sin embargo esta vez te dejo un link que te podria ayudar para que realices tu pregunta: [Aqui](https://goo.gl/kF3ATo)

Comment: Hola Fernando Godoy, bienvenido a SO en español. Por favor, échale un vistazo a [ask]. Es importante que aportes un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes pasarte también por el [tour] del sitio.

Comment: Esto ya se ha preguntado, revisa esta respuesta : http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39212/95

Comment: Se agradaría si podrías compartir tu código copiando y pegandolo, formateado con `CTRL`-`K`. Se veía mejor donde esta tu problema y facilitaría de agregarte una solución más concreta a la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para transferir objetos en un `Bundle` tienes que hacer tres cosas:

- Asegurarte que el objeto implementa `Serializable`
- Usar `putSerializable(String key, Serializable objeto)` para ponerlo al `Bundle`
- Usar `getSerializable(String key)` para obtenerlo del `Bundle`en tu actividad

Para implementar `Serializable` no tienes que hacer nada más que agregar `implements Serializable` a la definición de la clase (los tipicos objetos que uno usa por la mayoría ya lo implementan).

Cuando extraes el objeto del `Bundle` tienes que hacer un cast, con o sin comprobar con `instanceof` primero.

```
MiObjeto objeto = (MiObjeto) bundle.getSerializable("mi_objeto");
```

Comment: Ahi lo edite, y aun asi no me sale.

Comment: Y como esperas que te sale si en tu segunda actividad tu creas un nuevo `Bundle` vacío y luego tratas de sacar el objeto de eso en vez de leerlo desde el `Bundle` que Android te pasa en el `Intent`?

Comment: Bueno al fin salio, ya logre entender lo que me decias. Perdon es que soy demasiado nuevo en esto, y todavia no asocio la cosas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si quieres agradecerme, edita tu pregunta para que sería útil para los demás. También (como eres nuevo) te comento que en stackoverflow la forma preferida de agradecer es votar positivo en respuestas o comentarios útiles y/o aceptar respuestas que te solucionaban tu problema. El mejor agradecimiento en todo caso es de publicar preguntas tal cual que respuestas que sirven a la comunidad :) ¡Bienvenido!