# Pasar un dato a otra actividad que estoy consultando en un JSONArray

Tags: android, json, webservice

espero poder formular mi pregunta lo mas claro posible.
Estoy consumiendo un webservice de un login desde Android, este es el JSON que me devuelve el ws:

```
 "Table": [
    {
        "ID_USUARIO": 1,
        "USUARIO": "edson",
        "CONTRASENIA": "123",
        "TIPO": 1
    }
]
```

El login me funciona correctamente, y lo que quiero hacer es pasar el "ID_USUARIO" a otra actividad, pero no logro hacerlo, la aplicación siempre se me cierra y me muestra esto

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Esta la parte donde obtengo el arreglo y quiero capturar el ID_USUARIOS para mandarlo a otra actividad con el intent:

```
    try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(respuesta);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");
    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    Usuario u = new Usuario();
    u.setId_usuario(jsonData.getInt("ID_USUARIO"));
    u.setUsuario(jsonData.getString("USUARIO"));
    u.setContraseña(jsonData.getString("CONTRASENIA"));
    u.setTipo(jsonData.getInt("TIPO"));

    Intent i = null;

    switch (u.getTipo()) {
        case 1:
            u.setNom_tipo("Administrador");

            i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityConsultaVin.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            u.setNom_tipo("Usuario");
            i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityConsultaVin.class);
            break;
    }
    String id = (u.getId_usuario().toString());
    i.putExtra("u", u);
    i.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Donde tengo mi Intent aca y putextra (también lo he intentando con tipo int)

```
String id = (u.getId_usuario().toString());
i.putExtra("u", u);
i.putExtra("id", id);
```

Y en la otra actividad los estoy recibiendo con el Bundle:

```
        Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = datos.getString("id");
    txtIdUser.setText(id);
```

Pero no puedo lograr hacerlo, espero poder contar con la ayuda de ustedes, muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema que veo es que declaras el intent como nulo aquí: `Intent i = null;` luego, dentro del `switch` le asignas un `Intent` real, pero al setear los datos, estás fuera del bloque `switch`, donde el intent sigue siendo `null`, aquí: `String id = (u.getId_usuario().toString()); i.putExtra("u", u); i.putExtra("id", id);` tienes que decidir en qué casos quieres pasar esos datos al `Intent` y hacerlo dentro del `switch`, no fuera. Ese código no está del todo bien, porque si dejas el `startActivity(i); finish();` fuera del `switch`, si no se cumple ningún `case` la app fallará.

Comment: Lo probé de esa manera dentro del switch y el problema persiste aún :( y estoy usando sharedpreferences para el login, por eso el switch ahi amigo :D

Comment: Veo que en el switch estás comparando el id del usuario cuando al parecer lo que deberías comparar es el tipo del usuario por eso el intent se queda como nulo

Comment: Ya corregí eso amigo, tenias razón se me había ido por alto, aunque igual me sigue mostrando esto: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @HERNÁNDEZEDSON donde estas recibiendo el bundle, que mètodo de la Activity?

Comment: @Elenasys Lo estoy recibiendo en el onCreate de la otra actividad

Comment: @HERNÁNDEZEDSON te refieres a ActivityConsultaVin ? si es así entonces el problema es el parseo del JSON, el json se recibe con los contenedores {...} ? te sugiero agregar exactamente como recibes la respuesta.

Comment: @Elenasys me podrias ayudar como lo debería poner amigo, porque no entendí muy bien a lo que te refieres

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, actualice, para que sea objeto debe de estar dentro de los contenedores {..} si fuera array dentro de [..].

Comment: @Elenasys amigo me acaban de desabilitar mi cuenta de Azure for Student :'( solo veo como la habilito de nuevo, para poder seguir probando. :(

Comment: @Elenasys Amigo ya lo pude solucionar, en efecto como dice tu respuesta, el servicioweb lo creé desde php ahora y los datos están dentro de los contenedores {...}, te agradezco nuevamente por sacarme de apuros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente te puedo comentar que para enviar objetos entre Activities, la clase objeto debe implementar la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) o [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable):

```
public class Interstitial implements Serializable {
```

o también :

```
public class Interstitial implements Parcelable {
```

Así que debes asegurar esto.

Revisa:
[Enviar objetos entre Actividades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39212/95)

Pero el problema principal que obtienes:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

Se debe a que **es necesario recibir los valores del bundle dentro del método `onCreate()` de la `Activity` destino**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ... 
    Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (datos != null) { //Valida valor null
       String id = datos.getString("id");
       txtIdUser.setText(id);
    }
}
```

Pero al parecer el problema principal es que no se obtienen los datos en la Activity inicial. De acuerdo a el código para obtener los valores primero obtienes el valor del objeto,

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(respuesta);
```

pero tu respuesta no parece ser un objeto, si estuviera dentro de los contenedores `{...}` todo funcionaría sin problema.

```
 {"Table": [
    {
        "ID_USUARIO": 1,
        "USUARIO": "edson",
        "CONTRASENIA": "123",
        "TIPO": 1
    }
]}
```