# Falla en metodo setOnClickListener en cardview

Tags: android, recyclerview, onclick

Tengo el siguiente codigo para llenar un recyclerview con datos de mysql pero al agregar el metodo setOnClickListener para llamar al activitydetalles que me mostrara todos los detalles de cada registro me falla la aplicacion quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal. Anexo codigo e imagenes.

Clase UsuariosAdapter

```
package com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.adapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.DetallesUsuario;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.R;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.entidades.Usuario;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by CHENAO on 6/08/2017.
 */

public class UsuariosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuariosAdapter.UsuariosHolder>{

    List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
    Context context;

    public UsuariosAdapter(List<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
        this.listaUsuario = listaUsuarios;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.usuarios_list,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new UsuariosHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder,  @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        holder.txtNombre.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getNombre());
        holder.txtArea.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getArea());
        holder.txtReloj.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getReloj());
        holder.txtEquipo.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getEquipo());
        holder.txtFecha.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getFecha());

        holder.cvTarjeta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetallesUsuario.class);
                intent.putExtra("usuarios", (Parcelable) listaUsuario.get(i));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuario.size();
    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtReloj,txtNombre,txtArea,txtEquipo,txtFecha;
        CardView cvTarjeta;

        public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cvTarjeta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTarjeta);
            txtNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            txtArea= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtArea);
            txtReloj= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtReloj);
            txtEquipo= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipo);
            txtFecha= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);

        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment Clase donde lleno el recyclerview

```
package com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.ui.home;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.R;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.adapter.UsuariosAdapter;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.entidades.Usuario;
import com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.entidades.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    // RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ConsultarListaUsuariosFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerUsuarios= (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerUsuarios.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        cargarWebService();

        return vista;

    }

    private void cargarWebService() {

        progress=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setMessage("Consultando...");
        progress.show();

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/wsJSONConsultarLista.php";

        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se puede conectar "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
        progress.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Usuario usuario=null;

        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");

        try {

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                usuario=new Usuario();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

                usuario.setReloj(jsonObject.optString("reloj"));
                usuario.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
                usuario.setArea(jsonObject.optString("area"));
                usuario.setEquipo(jsonObject.optString("equipo"));
                usuario.setFecha(jsonObject.optString("fecha"));
                listaUsuarios.add(usuario);
            }
            progress.hide();
            UsuariosAdapter adapter=new UsuariosAdapter(listaUsuarios);
            recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                    " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.hide();
        }

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

El error que me manda el IDE es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revise mi codigo y me aparece esto en el metodo OnClick de la clase UsuariosAdapter ya revise y no encuentro el error me pueden ayudar u orientar para saber mi error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error es:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String Error: android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object
> reference

Te sugiero que en lugar de usar el valor de la variable `context`, uses el contexto de la vista mediante `v.getContext()`:

```
  holder.cvTarjeta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetallesUsuario.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetallesUsuario.class);
                intent.putExtra("usuarios", (Parcelable) listaUsuario.get(i));
                //context.startActivity(intent);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ahora me dice que el error es 

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.entidades.Usuario cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable`

Comment: Tu objeto Usuario debe extender de Parcelable, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259951/pasar-un-dato-a-otra-actividad-que-estoy-consultando-en-un-jsonarray/260006#260006

Comment: Gracias me ayudo pero ahora me arrojo otro error pero en uno de los edit text donde toma el valor del usuario lo seguire revisando pero me dio basicamente el errror de on a null object reference

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.Asociados.getIdUsuario()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Este es otro error diferente, Asociados tiene un id usuario con valor null